# Can Apache Camel File watch component work on remote file location?

Tags: apache-camel, file-watcher

I need to watch remote file location on file creation. when there is file created, copy this file from remote file location to cloud location and make some restful calls, then copy processed file back when it's ready from cloud to remote file location.

Apache camel file watch component seems like a good fit, but only found very little sample code, all related to local file location. anyone know if it can watch on remote location and copy file to cloud automatically? if it can, is there any comprehensive code sample for it instead of local file hello world one? i checked official examples, no code sample for file watch.

Comment: Have you tired mounting the remote file locally? If the file is available on the network you could create a network share and mount that as a local drive. Both Linux and Windows support this. Then you just read as if it was local.

Comment: @Namphibian, i haven't started development yet, only looking for solution. do you have any recommended solution based on above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The file-watch component is using the Java JVM file watcher (file system, eg java.nio.file.FileSystem) which requires to install 3rd party file systems to be able to watch in those systems.

I have not personally heard of anyone use this, but there may be some implementations out that that is reliable and you can use.

Comment: Hi @Claus, what 3rd party file system need to be installed? i can't find this requirement in official website. do you mean when watch on remote file location 3rd party file system 
 required or even local file location? is there alternative solution you recommended? thanks.

Comment: Hi @Claus, I knew you are Apache Camel guru and contributor. is it possible to give code sample for this component with actual user case like mine or at least have more comprehensive documentation, so ppls can start using this component?. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below route help. It is working for me.

```
<route id="sftpDownloadRoute">
        <log message="In sftp Download route"  logLevel="DEBUG" />
        <from uri="sftp:foo@localhost:1922/foo-home/download?knownHostsFile=./mounts/.ssh/known_hosts&password=pass&download=true" />
        <log message="${exchange}" logLevel="DEBUG" />

       <!--  <log message="${exchange['CamelFileHost']}" logLevel="DEBUG" /> -->
        <to uri="file:/home/tmp/download/to-loc" />
        <log message="Download completed"  logLevel="DEBUG" />
    </route>
```